# Databinding uri source of imagebrush

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-10, win-universal-app

In my application i am binding several properties to a custom user control, and everything works fine, except the images are not showing. For binding i have used the following codes:

```
Categories.Add(new Models.Category { Name = "Pizza", Count= 4, ImageUri = new Uri("Images/pizza.png", UriKind.Relative) });
```

I have also tried with different urikinds but the images are never showing.
what could go wrong? The images are in my solutions Images folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ms-appx` URI scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx):

```
ImageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/pizza.png");
```

Take care to really write `///`.

Also make sure that the `Build Action` of the image file is set to `Content`, as pointed out in the other answer. Setting `Copy to Output Directory` does however not seem to be necessary.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem,
Actually i also tried that before ( copied it from the xaml imagebrush's source) but some extra space got inside of it and that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you set the properties of the image so that it is available during runtime. Sometimes if employing Design Time data in Blend, you will see the images in Design Time, but then nothing during run time. The reason is that the images were never deployed with the rest of the solution. Be sure the Build Action on each image is set to Content and I usually set the Copy to Output Directory to Copy if Newer.

[image: Image Properties in Visual Studio 2015]